# Let $T = \{\frac ab \in \Bbb Q \mid \text{$a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and $5 \nmid b$}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $T = \{\frac ab \in \Bbb Q \mid \text{$a$ and $b$ are relatively prime and $5 \nmid  b$}\}$ . Show that $T$ is a ring under usual addition and multiplication. Also prove that $I = \{\frac ab \in T : 5\mid a \}$ is an ideal of $T$ and the quotient ring $T/I$ is a field.

I am having a problem in doing the problem!!

Let $x,y \in T$, then $x = \frac ab$ and $y = \frac cd$ and $\gcd(a,b) =1$ and $\gcd(c,d) =1$.

Having problem in the part to show that the ring is closed with respect to addition!!

Comment: What part are you having a problem with?

Comment: Having problem in the part to show that the ring is closed with respect to addition!!

Comment: Note: usually in abstract algebra, this $T$ is constructed not as a subset of $\Bbb Q$, but as an extension of $\Bbb Z$. You basically take the ring of integers, and then you include inverses of every element that is _not_ divisible by $5$. This is called the _localization_ of $\Bbb Z$ at the ideal $(5)$. The rational numbers is the localization of $\Bbb Z$ at the ideal $(0)$ (every element in $\Bbb Z$ that is not in the ideal $(0)$ has an inverse in $\Bbb Q$, and $\Bbb Q$ is the smallest extension of the integers where this is true). This can be done in any ring and with any _prime_ ideal.

Comment: @tone $\ a/b + c/d = (ad+bc)/(bd).\,$ By $\,5\,$ prime, $\,5\nmid b,d\,\Rightarrow\,5\nmid bd,\,$ When the fraction is reduced to lowest terms by cancelling the gcd, the denominator is a factor of $\,bd\,$ so remains coprime to $\,5.\,$ Similarly for the product of fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the things you need to do to cover all of those parts.

1. Show that addition works at all.  In particular, that when you add two fractions whose denominators are not divisible by $5$, one obtains a fraction whose denominator is not divisible by $5$.
2. Note that commutativity and associativity of addition are inherited from $\mathbb{Q}$.  And the additive identity $0\in T$ is $\frac{0}{1}$, for instance.
3. Show that multiplication works at all.  Again, the product of two elements of $T$ has a denominator which is not divisible by $5$.
4. Again, commutativity and associativity are inherited.  And the multiplicative identity $1\in T$ shows up as $\frac{1}{1}$, for instance.  Distributivity is also inherited.

These together prove $T$ is a ring.  Now for $I$ being an ideal.

5. To show $I$ is closed under addition, one must show that the sum of two fractions whose numerators are divisible by $5$ is itself a fraction whose numerator is divisible by $5$.
6. To show $I$ is closed under multiplication by $T$, one must show that the product's numerator is divisible by $5$.  For this, let both of the fractions be reduced, and show that the denominator is *not* divisible by $5$ (otherwise the numerator might lose its $5$'s!).

So $I$ is an ideal.

7. The quotient $T/I$ being a field is equivalent to saying $I$ is a maximal ideal in $T$.  There are a number of ways to tackle this, one is to show that if $x\in T\setminus I$, then $I+xT=T$.  (In fact, this equation can be used to find a multiplicative inverse of $x$ for any $x$, thereby showing $T/I$ is a field directly, if you wish.)

Hopefully this is enough of an outline.